# maven post build copy files

Tags: maven, openfire, maven-antrun-plugin, maven-resources-plugin

I am currently working with a specific project structure.

All the jar files inside `project\WEB-INF\lib` which is prepared to create a WAR in target folder should be copied into `project\lib`

Can we run such script either using maven-antrun or maven-resource plugin, which will trigger before actual WAR is created?

If Yes, then how to program it? The files should not be moved, it should be copied.

**EDIT**

Figured out the solution using following xml and working fine, This structure required for openfire plugin

But unfortunately it only happens when second time `mvn package` is executed

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.hpe.sis</groupId>
  <artifactId>TestCopy</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>TestCopy Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.jersey/jersey-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.19.1</version>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>TestCopy</finalName>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>copy-resources</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>copy-resources</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/TestCopy/lib</outputDirectory>
              <resources>
                <resource>
                  <directory>${basedir}/target/TestCopy/WEB-INF/lib</directory>
                  <filtering>false</filtering>
                </resource>
              </resources>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Yes. (your question is a yes no answer?) In all seriousness, check http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/
I don't understand why you need to move jar files.

Comment: Something is seriously wrong with your set-up. You shouldn't copy JAR, you shouldn't even have JAR in your project. Can you post your POM and what you exactly want to do? Can you give more context?

Comment: I want to create a openfire plugin using `maven-archetype-webapp` archetype

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `copy-rename-maven-plugin`plugin for that:

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.coderplus.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>copy-rename-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>copy-file</id>
            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>copy</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <sourceFile>src/someDirectory/test.environment.properties</sourceFile>
              <destinationFile>target/someDir/environment.properties</destinationFile>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

For more informations see: http://coderplus.github.io/copy-rename-maven-plugin/usage.html